# SharePoint 2019 Site Library Files missing (Open with explorer view and mapped network drive)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2019, file, mapped-folder, network-drive

I have mapped the SharePoint Site Library as a network drive on the same SharePoint server.

However, some files are not appearing in the File system but the same files are appearing in the SharePoint site accessed through browser using same user account (Farm account used in both cases).

Following points were tried but no luck:

1. Tried to replicate the same in another system.
2. Also, I tried to map and access using different accounts.
3. Even tried opening the library with "Open with explorer" option but same issue encountered.

Note:

1. Library does not have content approval enabled or check in/ check out issues.
2. There are only around 38 files in library.
3. No folders present in this library.

Basic requirement was to move the files across the site, so once the file was mapped it was really fast in performance to read the file from File System using `OpenBinaryDirect` method of csom code and moved it to different site.

**Edit**:
Facing following issue with OneDrive sync in SP Library.

Added registry entries as per [Article](https://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/Media/WindowsLiveWriter/SharePoint2019andthenewOneDriveSyncClien_CD03/image_3.png) but still no luck.

[image]

Any help is much appreciated to fulfill above requirement.

Comment: Do all files have a checked in version? (if you are using check in/check out)

Comment: @CallumCrowley All files are checked in.
Not using check in/ check out.

Comment: How big are the files that are missing?

Comment: @CallumCrowley around 4 MB,
files that are visible are also similar size

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things you can check to narrow down this issue:

1. Make sure the issued files do not contain special characters that are not supported for syncing (`\, /, :, *, ?, ", <, >, | , # , %`, etc.).
2. Make sure the files do not exceed the **256-character** limit on Network Folder Paths (starting with the first backslash in the path name). You can rename the files in SharePoint to a shorter one and then check again.
3. If the issue persists, try syncing with [OneDrive sync app](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/new-onedrive-sync-client) instead.

Reference: [Restrictions and limitations when you sync SharePoint libraries to your computer through OneDrive for work or school.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/restrictions-and-limitations-when-you-sync-sharepoint-libraries-to-your-computer-through-onedrive-for-work-or-school-14fdf1b3-61e5-49cd-a9e1-a66588505b4e)

Comment: 1. Missing files were having underscore but the visible files were also having underscores. 
2. Also, there was no character limit. It was really small file names.
3. Tried the OneDrive Sync but facing error, posted screenshot in edited post.

Comment: @SohailShaikh Would it be accessible if you download one of the issued files from SharePoint, and then upload it manually to the network drive? As for the OneDrive sync app configuration, my experience is that it does not work if set on SharePoint server, but it works if configured on the domain controller.

Comment: I have set up the OneDrive configuration on DC but in the last step after clicking "Sync" option from SP Library, I was prompted with Microsoft account. Post authentication it showed me "Sorry, OneDrive can't add your folder right now." Can you help me on the same?
I have even created the necessary folders in local File System.

Comment: @SohailShaikh This seems like a common issue in OneDrive. See the UserVoice post here for discussion in the Comment section: https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive-archive/suggestions/19588537-fix-the-sorry-onedrive-can-t-add-your-folder-rig There are a couple of troubleshooting methods besides creating folders manually. Hope it can do some help.